# Is there a way to track the date the pending payment record was created once payment has been completed?

Tags: contributions, payment

I create a pending contribution for a membership with the received date of 1st July.

I then go in and complete the contribution on the 7th of August.

I cannot find where in Civi the original pending payment invoice date of 1st July is stored.

What I see happening is all received dates (including in the invoice) change to 7 of August.

Is there anywhere where the original date is stored once the payment is completed?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a field on contribution that stores when the Contribution was created v/s payment added to the contribution. But you can get such information from financial transactions table.

When a pending contribution is created a account receivable(IR) entry is created in financial transaction table and later a new entry is created with income account when a payment is received. But AR transactions are not displayed on UI when you click on contribution amount(which loads list of payments).

The only place you can see them is while creating [accounting batches](https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/contributions/accounting-integration/).

Answer (score 2):

This will change in a CiviCRM release coming to you in the near future!

This was merged 8 days ago:
https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/17777